# What does printf print for an unitialized variable?

Tags: c, global

What should the code print? 0 or any garbage value or will it depend on the compiler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a;
int main() 
{ 
   printf("%d\n",a);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Kmysrer Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Oscar mederos : i don't have access to a compiler right now.

Comment: @Kmysrer: How did you know the question was "simple" if you didn't know the answer?

Comment: @AndreyT: I am not sure that not knowing the answer is a prerequisite for asking a question on SO.  SO also has a lot of value as a knowledge repository

Comment: AndreyT i expected the question to be simple for you all.

Comment: @Kmysrer: http://codepad.org is a free compiler available online

Comment: To ask if time travel is possible is a very simple question... :)

Comment: @Kmysrer: Can you change your title to one that is searchable for people who have a similar question in the future?

Comment: @Kmysrer - Your answer - http://codepad.org/FKsI5iPf

Comment: I added `#include <stdio.h>` because I'm pretty sure this question is about initialization of global variables, not about what happens when you're missing the prototype for a variadic function.

Comment: Also answering "try it and see" is often a poor answer to C and C++ questions. It doesn't tell you when you're invoking undefined or implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 9):

the answer is 0. Global variables are initialized to zero.

Comment: Considering the code in the opening post this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Oh wonder, karthik answers on a question that is potentially not asked by his alter user account.

Answer (score 4):

I would say your code might output anything or simply anything can happen because your code invokes Undefined Behaviour as per C99.

You don't have a prototype for `printf` in scope.

> J.2 Undefined behavior
>
> — For call to a function without a function prototype in scope where the function is defined with a function prototype, either the prototype ends with an ellipsis or the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters (6.5.2.2).

If the question is about initialization of global variables then `a` would be initialized to `0` because it has static storage duration.

Comment: @John : If you consider the code in the original post my answer is relevant and correct. The code might be about "initialization of global variables" but it was not specifically mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I found on C99 standard, Section 6.7.8.10, Initialization:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
>   then:
>   — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>   — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
>   — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules.

Section 6.2.4.3 defines:

> An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal linkage, or with the
>   storage-class specifier static has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire
>   execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program
>   startup.

In other words, globals are initialized as 0. Automatic variables (i.e. non-`static` locals) are not automatically initialized.

Comment: While it's a bit unclear what you mean by "internal", unless by "internal" you mean "automatic", the last sentence is very wrong. All variable of static storage duration, whether they have external linkage or not, are implicitly initialized to zero if not explicitly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

without automatic variable [generally what we use in function in most cases] all other variable's value is assigned to 0

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are initialized as 0. Automatic variables (i.e. non-static locals) are not automatically initialized.