# Why does value of automatic object persist after lifetime ends?

Tags: c, output

I'm preparing for a job interview.

My c program is :

```
void foo(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}

void bar(void)
{
    int a=42;
}

void main(void)
{
    bar();
    foo();
}
```

I'm getting the output as : 42

But how? I thought it would be some garbage value .

How the concept of execution stack or activation frame is applied in this?

Please explain

Thanks

Comment: `42` is a perfectly sensible garbage value

Comment: The votes to close as caused by “a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error” are off the mark. This question is neither. It can be reproduced in most C implementations by turning off optimization, and it is clearly not a typographical error.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I perfectly understand why somebody wouldn't like your post: (1) the question title contains not much information, it talks about your personal problem, not about the technical question that you encounter (2) any good book or other resource should tell you that you should not print variables that are not initialized with a value (3) with sufficient warning levels, any decent compiler nowadays should just cry.

Comment: @JensGustedt: (2) is irrelevant. The OP does not ask whether this is good practice or not or why. They ask a different question, why is this behavior observed when it is not within the behavior specified by the C standard. As a matter of fact, reasons for that do exist, and the reasons lie within the realm of computer programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does printf print for an unitialized variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972978/what-does-printf-print-for-an-unitialized-variable)

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you are right that these are not the good reasons, but the fact that we have seen that a lot of times.

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794 but many of the ideas expressed in that answer are germane. Basically: you are relying on undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. **Something does happen**.  "Something" is a subset of "anything".

Answer (score 5):

`a` is not initialized in function `foo`. Printing an uninitialized variable invokes **undefined behavior**.
In this case you may get anything, either expected or unexpected result. On my compiler the output is

```
 4203214
```

The result may vary compiler to compiler, even different versions of same compiler could give you different results.
But one of the possible reason that you are getting `42` is because auto variables are often allocated on an execution stack. After the call of `bar`, `42` is placed on execution stack. This value remains in stack undisturbed. When `foo` is called, it *might* read that stack space for `a` and prints `42`.
Try to optimize your code (compile with `-o`), you may get some different value for `a`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect because “undefined behavior” is never a **cause** of any behavior; it is a **lack of a cause**. There **do exist** reasons why the behavior the OP observed occurred. Those reasons lie in how function calls and automatic variables are typically implemented.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; The why I am getting different result?

Comment: @haccks: You are getting a different result because your C implementation behaves differently than the OP’s C implementation. But that difference is not **caused** by the fact that the C standard does not define the behavior. It is caused by decisions made by the implementors of the two C implementations. The fact that the OP observes output of “42” is undoubtedly caused by the fact that 42 is placed on the stack by `bar`, remains there undisturbed, and is found there when `foo` uses it. The C standard did not cause this. The use of a stack did.

Comment: @EricPostpischil; But `a` is uninitialized. Doesn't that invokes UB?

Comment: @haccks: The phrase “invokes UB” is misguided. Let’s say you are a parent, and your teenage child goes out for the afternoon, and you do not tell them where to go. Your child goes to see a movie. That is undefined behavior: You did not specify they had to go to a movie. Did you cause them to go to a movie? Did you invoke their undefined behavior? If somebody asked why your child went to a movie, would you say they went to a movie because you did not specify where they had to go? It just does not make any sense. You did not invoke anything. It happened for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `bar()` puts the value `42` on the stack. It is still there when `foo()` is called.

The stack frames of `bar()` and `foo()` are likely identical, or a least similar enough, so that the `a` in `foo()` keeps the value `42`.

Of course, this is not guaranteed, and is Undefined Behavior.  But rather than simply dismissing such questions, as is often done, for *debugging* code one often needs some understanding.

If you increase the optimizing level (at least in gcc), the behaviour you see would change.

Comment: The last sentence should say “may change” rather than “would change”.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `bar()` from `main()`, it sets `a = 42` which lives on the stack one int down from where `main()` executes. When you call `foo()` from `main()` it prints the value of `a` which in this scope is also on the stack one int down from where `main()` executes.

By calling `bar()` first, you have set data on the stack, and since `foo()` and `bar()` have the same call frame, `bar()`'s `a` and `foo()`'s `a` end up in the same memory address.

As other answers have noted, though, this is undefined behavior. In this case, the value persists on the stack and ends up in the same location.